# Query selector for this component only

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I am adding a height to my div like this:

```
  const parentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let collapseHeight = parentRef.current.scrollHeight   
    const collapse = document.querySelector('.collapse-content-parent')
    collapse.style.height = collapseHeight + "px" 
  }, []);
```

This just selects the first div on the page when there are multiple instances of the same component.

I'd like to do something like swapping the `querySelector` for my ref so it's sepecific to the component:

```
  const parentRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let collapseHeight = parentRef.current.scrollHeight   
    parentRef.style.height = collapseHeight + "px" 
  }, []);
```

But the above comes back as:

`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'height')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `parentRef.style.height`  use this `parentRef.current.style.height` .

Comment: That did the trick, is "current" equivalent to "this" in this situation?

Comment: Not really. using Ref hook , U get back an object, by observing it U can see what's inside. Like U would with an API. By the way , in some cases U might need to use 'currentTarget'. It's slightly different from 'current'. U should check that out too.